# 英語が残っている: This user has no recent reputation changes

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

サンプル: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

[image: This user has no recent reputation changes]

Answer (score 2):

文が2つ未翻訳らしいです：

- `This user has no recent [reputation changes]($helpLink$)`
- `This user has no recent positive [reputation changes]($helpLink$)`

(`$helpLink$`はヘルプへのリンクです)

翻訳として、下記は大丈夫ですか？

- `このユーザーは、直近で[信用度の変化]($helpLink$)がありません`
- `このユーザーは、直近で[信用度が上がった]($helpLink$)履歴がありません`

Comment: 翻訳を私なりに自然に聞こえるようになおしました